# Win32 API windows remain processing and can't be closed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I coded to make a window using win32 api in VS 2017, the code seems correct but when executed the windows shows up and keeps on processing and when closed, it will be closed but keeps on processing in background and I have to manually shut it down but [Stop Debugging] button in VS.

CODE::

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASSEX wc;
ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";
if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    return 1;

CREATESTRUCT ws;
ZeroMemory(&ws, sizeof(CREATESTRUCT));
ws.style = WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
RECT wr{ 0,0,800,600 };
AdjustWindowRectEx(&wr, ws.style, FALSE, 0);
ws.x = 0;   ws.y = 0;
ws.cx = wr.right - wr.left; ws.cy = wr.bottom - wr.top;
ws.hInstance = hInstance;
ws.lpszClass = wc.lpszClassName;
ws.lpszName = L"Window1";
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(ws.dwExStyle, ws.lpszClass, ws.lpszName, ws.style, ws.x, ws.y, ws.cx, ws.cy, ws.hwndParent, ws.hMenu, ws.hInstance, ws.lpCreateParams);
if (!hWnd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Window could not be created!", L"ERROR!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

MSG msg;
while (true)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
    }
}

UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, wc.hInstance);
return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Lose the `hWnd` argument to [PeekMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943(v=vs.85).aspx). Just pass NULL instead. WM_QUIT, posted by PostQuitMessage, is a thread-message, not targeted to a specific window, which means PeekMessage will never fetch it, and your loop will never break. And you should seriously be using `GetMessage` instead, btw.

Comment: and `PeekMessage` in exactly this loop very bad choice. you most time spin in look and take cpu time

Comment: It's not like there aren't countless examples showing how to write message loops. Find one and copy it.